# A DIY solution for IDC cable

Tags: connector, cables, ribbon-cable, wire-terminals

I need Ribbon Cable with IDC female header 8pins (2x4) on one side and separate female sockets (2.54mm pitch) on the other side. Like this cables:

[image]

But I can't find appropriate cable, the available item have two 2x4 8-Pin IDC headers on both ends.

[image]

Therefore, does it possible a DIY solution, what I mean is crack IDC header on one side and pull out a separate crimp sockets.

[image]

Then insert these crimp sockets into standard separate 2.54mm female plastic sockets. I don't know how the wires are mounted inside these IDC headers, does they use same crimp sockets as in regular 2.54mm female sockets, or other type of crimp sockets?

Comment: Crimp sockets are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDC stands for *insulation-displacement contact*; it works by having a set of tiny blades that pierce the insulation. If you undo the clips at the side of the IDC connector you can take the back off and dismantle it to see how it works.

It should be perfectly possible to buy a set of crimp connectors, cut off the IDC from one end of the cable and start stripping and attaching crimp connectors to the wires. A little time-consuming though.

Comment: yes, it obvious way, but it requires a quality crimper which I have no.

Comment: For crimps like those that aren't really tiny you can do an acceptable job with needlenose pliers and a bit of practice.

Comment: So buy a 2x8 connector and cut the cable in two.  Solder (and insulate) wires with the single connectors to the wires on the 2x8 connectors.  Wires like that are also comnercially available.

Comment: Buy cables with "dupont" style headers on both sides and just back out the crimped pins using tweezers on one side and insert them into a 2x4 "dupont" header. Or cut off one end and manually put on the IDC connector.

Answer (score 1):

One option and cut off proto board end.
[Option one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/8-WAY-MULTI-CONNECTION-ISP-LEAD-/110686039324)

[image: Header to Ribbon]
Personally, I'd buy ribbon cable with female to female jumpers no housing and empty sockets, by 1 and 2 by 4 and build what I need.  [Option Two](https://protostack.com.au/shop/cables/200mm-female-to-female-jumpers-without-housing-ribbon-of-40/)

[image: Female to Female Jumpers]

Answer (score 1):

I would buy the cables with the individual pin crimps, cut/split them and fit IDC connectors. Given a choice between fitting the individual pin crimps myself and fitting the IDC connectors myself, I would choose the latter in a heartbeat.

Individual pin crimps are fiddly and annoying. IDC connectors are really quick to fit, slide the cable in, squeeze the connector and job done. They make special tools for squeezing them but my experience is that a cheap vice (something like https://cpc.farnell.com/duratool/d00099/vice-table-swivel-60mm/dp/TL10308 will do the job if you don't already have a vice) does the job just as well.